# creating sequence diagram using visio interop APIs

Tags: c#, automation, interop, visio, sequence-diagram

Trying to generate Visio sequence diagrams programatically. Below is a working piece of the code

```
namespace Training.Visio
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            var sequenceDrawer = new VisioSequenceDrawer();
            sequenceDrawer.MakeObjectLifelineShape("obj1", 1, 1);
            sequenceDrawer.MakeObjectLifelineShape("obj2", 2, 1);

            var shape1 = sequenceDrawer.GetShapeByName("obj1");
            var shape2 = sequenceDrawer.GetShapeByName("obj2");

            sequenceDrawer.ConnectShapes(shape1, shape2);

            //sequenceDrawer.ActiveDocument.Save();
            //sequenceDrawer.ActiveDocument.Close();
        }
    }
    public class VisioSequenceDrawer
    {
        private Application application;
        private Masters masters;
        private Page activePage;
        private Document activeDocument;
        public VisioSequenceDrawer()
        {
            this.application = new Application();
            this.application.Documents.Add(string.Empty);
            var documents = this.application.Documents;
            var document = documents.OpenEx("UMLSEQ_U.VSS", (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
            this.masters = document.Masters;
            this.activeDocument = this.application.ActiveDocument;
            this.activePage = this.activeDocument.Pages.Add();
        }
        public Document ActiveDocument
        {
            get
            {
                return this.activeDocument;
            }
        }
        public void MakeObjectLifelineShape(string name, double x, double y)
        {
            var masterShape  = this.GetMaster("Object Lifeline");
            var lifelineShape = this.activePage.Drop(masterShape, x, y);
            lifelineShape.Name = name;
            lifelineShape.Text = name;
        }
        public void ConnectShapes(Shape frmShape, Shape endShape)
        {
            var masterArrow = this.GetMaster("Message");
            var arrowShape = this.activePage.Drop(masterArrow, 9, 9);

            var frmCell = arrowShape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)VisCellIndices.vis1DBeginX);
            var endCell = arrowShape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)VisCellIndices.vis1DEndX);
            // code under question
            // able to only connect to the end of the lifeline
            frmCell.GlueTo(frmShape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts, (short)VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX));
            endCell.GlueTo(endShape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts, (short)VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX));
        }
        public Shape GetShapeByName(string name)
        {
            IEnumerable<Shape> shapes = from Shape shape in this.activePage.Shapes where name == shape.Name select shape;
            return shapes.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        private Master GetMaster(string mastername)
        {
            return this.masters.ItemU[mastername];
        }
    }
}
```

Im having trouble connecting the message arrows between different object lifelines.
The code following the comments

// able to only connect to the end of the lifeline

Works but Im not able to
1. Programatically lengthen the vertical lifeline in that Shape object
2. By default that object has at least 3 connection points that we can "glue" the message arrows. But not able to programatically select the connection points

Any inputs on how to go about these 2 issues?